# How to access the properties of a logged-in user?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc-2.0

I am learning Asp.net Core MVC 2.0 and cannot figure out how to access the properties of a logged-in user.

For illustration purpose, let's use the default template of Asp.net Core MVC 2.0 generated by Visual Studio Community with `Individual User Account` selected.

The template provides us with an empty `ApplicationUser` that inherits from `IdentityUser`. Again, for simplicity, I added just one property `Point` to the `ApplicationUser` as follows.

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public int Point { get; set; }
}
```

The `Point` will keep track the number of times a logged-in user visits "/Home/Index". It is a trivial scenario for simplicity.

## Question

Now, I have no idea how to access the property `Point` and increment it by one every time he/she visits `/Home/Index`.

I attempted to access the property `Point` via `User.Identity` is shown as follows, but failed.

[image]

Could you tell me the correct way?

Comment: did you try casting with (ApplicationUSer)User.Identity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, and refer to your question, you can also update Point:

```
private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;

public HomeController(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager)
{
    _userManager = userManager;
}

public async Task<IActionResult> GetCurrentUserAsync()
{
   var currentUser = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(User);
   if (currentUser is null)
   {
       //handle this as you wish
   }
   currentUser.Point++;
   await _usermanager.UpdateAsync(currentUser);
}
```

Comment: Sorry. Is there any documentation about this technique?

Comment: @ArtificialStupidity sure, [here it is](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?tabs=visual-studio%2Caspnetcore2x)

Comment: @ArtificialStupidity i've read that page, then tried to use all methods of `UserManager` and `SignInManager`.